# Relationships from multiple non-unique data sources in Power BI

Tags: relationship, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling, multiple-databases

I have an interesting problem. I am trying to create a relationship from an Excel File containing 'Business Days' with only Dates/Month Name/Days/Year and connecting that to a SQL Database source in Power BI that contains similar Date Fields as the other table but there is not unique identifier such as Customer ID...
The fields in the SQL source are Currency, receipt date, and system created date.

When I try to create the relationship on the Date level I don't get the desired result in working with the visual.
Does anyone have any guidance?

I've tested new relationships based on the Date fields from both data sources theoretically tying Year to Year, Month to Month, but this won't change the currency value to follow the Year/Month/Day.
Not sure what else I can combine to with these sources since there are no unique identifiers.

I also tried Appending the two data sources but it converted all my excel dates into NULL values... enter image description here

Comment: Update your question with example tables in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) to help explain the challenge.

Comment: I was able to finally connect the working days spreadsheet to my SQL database via the correct Date Fields. It took some trial and error but once I realized how the balances were being tracked then I was able to connect the two and have them function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect the two tables via the correct date fields. My excel workbook connected to the 'Receipt Date' of my SQL server table and I can now use the dates in the Excel table to manipulate balances from the SQL server table.